# 2 Mesh.Box among each other

Tags: c#, directx, managed-directx

I use directx with C# (MDX). And my Task is it so put two Boxes (created with Mesh.Box) among each other.

The top box has:

width: 200
height: 10
depth: 1

The bottom box has:

width: 10
height: 100
depth: 1

Both together should look like

```
-----------
          -
          -
          -
          -
```

Now I have the Problem, that i don't know how to calcultate the right Translation for both:

Top Box:

```
d3dDevice.Transform.World = Matrix.Translation(0, 20, 30.0f);
```

Bottom Box:

```
d3dDevice.Transform.World = Matrix.Translation(195, -40, 30.0f);
```

Now the bottom Box isn't direct among the top box.

I think that I must calculate Z but I don't know how i do this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The created boxes are centered at the origin. So the only thing you have to do is adjusting the x and y-coordinate. The top box has to be `bottom height / 2 + top height / 2` units higher than the bottom one and `top width / 2 - bottom width / 2` units to the left. So:

```
//top box
d3dDevice.Transform.World = Matrix.Translation(-195, 55, 0);

//bottom box
d3dDevice.Transform.World = Matrix.Identity();
```

Or

```
//top box
d3dDevice.Transform.World = Matrix.Translation(0, 55, 0);

//bottom box
d3dDevice.Transform.World = Matrix.Translation(195, 0, 0);
```

Apart from that you can specify any other transformation. As long as you apply it to both boxes. E.g. move the boxes around:

```
//top box
d3dDevice.Transform.World = Matrix.Translation(30, 75, 30);

//bottom box
d3dDevice.Transform.World = Matrix.Translation(225, 20, 30);
```